# Number format with a variable decimal place

Tags: php

Is there a built-in/neat way to format a number (just like `number_format` does), but without any rounding ups/downs?

For instance, number `1234.234` should be formatted as `1,234.234` and another number `1234` should be formatted as `1,234` (i.e. without any trailing `.000`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rtrim(number_format(1234.234, 3),'.0');
rtrim(number_format(1234, 3),'.0');
```

Comment: Rather than just pasting a random bunch of code, explain what you did and why. That way, the OP and any future readers with the same problem can actually learn something from your answer, rather than just copy/pasting it and asking the same question again tomorrow.

Comment: What kind of explanation needed? We format number and trim trailing zeros?

Comment: In itself your answer doesn't explain this is what the code does. It's just some code, so the answer now assumes you know what rtrim() even does and what the arguments mean.

Comment: Googling `php rtrim` will do the trick just fine. I don't think we should discourage the OP from googling, because this will just cause more questions being opened which could have been solved by simply copying their title into Google.

Comment: This is a good an elegant solution. Thanks! Although @Oldskool is right about giving some explanation. This answer will be viewed by others in the future, who dont understand PHP as well as you do. Just for the sake of the community ))

Comment: Smart solution, Note it won't do what is expected if locale is set to one whose decimal separator is not ".". See my answer for an explanation (I agree with @Oldskool and @AVK), and discussion about the decimal count value.

Comment: And moreover, as others have stated, numbers like '2100' will be truncated of their last zeroes.

Answer (score 4):

You can define simple custom function for that:

```
<?php
    function custom_number_format($number, $decimal = '.')
    {
        $broken_number = explode($decimal, $number);
        if (isset($broken_number[1]))
            return number_format($broken_number[0]) . $decimal . $broken_number[1];
        else
            return number_format($broken_number[0]);
    }

    $n1 = '1234.234';
    $n2 = '1234';

    echo custom_number_format($n1);
    echo '<br>';
    echo custom_number_format($n2);
?>
```

Output is:

```
1,234.234
1,234
```

Comment: Thank you! Nice solution, but i do like @arhey's solution more, as it does not involve writing your own function.

Comment: Solution which not solves the problem when you have dynamic number of digits after the dot (like 12345.1313131 or 1234.4321). With such function you don't need to care about the length. But if covers your needs is fine.

Answer (score 4):

*Based on the arhey's answer*

**TLDR ;)**

You can use `number_format` to format the number to a fixed-width format, then use `rtrim` twice to remove trailing zeroes, and dot.

```
rtrim(rtrim(number_format($number, 3, '.', ','), '0'), '.')
```

Starting from the last character, rtrim removes it while it is one of those given. In our case, we remove trailing dots, then we remove an eventual trailing zero.

```
rtrim(rtrim(number_format(1234.123, 3, '.', ','), '0'), '.')
// returns 1,234.123

rtrim(rtrim(number_format(1234.12, 3, '.', ','), '0'), '.')
// returns 1,234.12 (1,234.120, trimmed to 1234.12)

rtrim(rtrim(number_format(1234, 3, '.', ','), '0'), '.')
// returns 1,234 (1,234.000, trimmed to 1234)

rtrim(rtrim(number_format(1200, 3, '.', ','), '0'),'.')
// returns 1,200 (1,200.000, trimmed to 1200., trimmed to 1200)
```

**Formal form, and discussion about the parameters (notably the decimals count)**

```
rtrim(rtrim(number_format($number, <N>, '<D>', ''), '0'), '<D>')
```

Where :

- **D** is the decimal separator. To avoid locale-formatting problems, explicitly specify it
- **N** is the maximum digits you number can have.

If you know all your numbers will have less than 3 digits, go and take N=3.

What if you don't know how many decimals are at most ? Well, things are getting more complex.
It may worth recalling (as stated in [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)) that floats are stored :

- with a *precision* (a number of digits, without distinction whether they are before or after the decimal separator), not a number of decimals
- and in their *binary* form, not their decimal one, and that can lead to rounding errors when reaching precision limit.

> For example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the
> expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like
> 7.9999999999999991118....

So there is no universal good value, you'll have to choose it depending on the usual scale of your data.

And that explains why there is no built-in function for that : PHP can't choose for you.

Comment: This answer should be accepted instead of the current one. It is clear, complete and takes into account the current locale and all possible input numbers, unlike the current accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use function:

```
<?php
function getNumberFormat($number) {
    $numberAr = explode('.', (string)$number);

    $count = 0;
    if (2 === count($numberAr)) {
        $count = strlen($numberAr[1]);
    }

    return number_format($number, $count, ',', '.');
}

$test1 = 1234.234;
$test2 = 1234;                      
echo getNumberFormat($test1); //1,234.234
echo getNumberFormat($test2); //1,234
```

Answer (score 1):

I really liked arhey's answer, but later realized it has a major flaw. A number like `2100` will get converted to `2,1` instead of `2,100`.

Below is how I ended up modifying it.

```
public function formatDecimal($number)
{
    $stringVal = strval($number); //convert number to string

    $decPosition = strpos($stringVal, ".");

    if ($decPosition !== false) //there is a decimal
    {
        $decPart = substr($stringVal, $decPosition); //grab only the decimal portion

        $result = number_format($stringVal) . rtrim($decPart, ".0");
    }
    else //no decimal to worry about
    {
        $result = number_format($stringVal);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

It's not as succinct a solution as I was hoping, but in my case I put it into a view helper (I'm using ZF2) and so it's just one simple function call in my view.

Hope this is helpful for someone!

Comment: i found the same flaw. something like `rtrim(rtrim(number_format(2100, 3), '0'), '.')` should do the trick, right?

Comment: @sashn I like it! Makes sense to me and a lot less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin with that there's  no decimal type in PHP. There's float only.

And if you know how float works, then you know that it's usually not possible to store exact decimal value that you think you have, but it's an approximation. That's because you can't express most of decimal numbers in binary system.

Therefore if you say:

```
$number = 1234.234;
```

Then you have a float that is close to this value. The real value is:

```
1234.23399999999992360244505107402801513671875
```

Therefore PHP can't just guess how do you want to round it. It needs to be specified explicitly.

Comment: I very well know how float works and im not looking for PHP to guess anything. I just dont want any unnecessary padded 0's in my formatted numbers. As an example, you can take a look at http://numeraljs.com/

Comment: But the thing is that in practice once you have float variable, there are usually no 0's, but other digits as I showed you in my answer. Also JS is never a good example. Take a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp , Precision secion. It shows you that it's not always working as you expect. And yes JS is sometimes guessing how to number should look like.